# How can I remove a key from a Python dictionary?

Tags: python, keyerror

In my python program I am getting this error:

```
KeyError('followers')
```

From this code :

```
for u in r["followers"]: 
with open(r'data.csv', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
writer = csv.writer(f)
row = {}
for x in fieldnames:
    if x in u and u[x]:
        row[x] = str(u[x])
        if x == "uid":
            row[x] = str(u[x]) + ''
            
            writer = csv.DictWriter(
                f, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Can anyone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: (1) Format the code correctly. (2) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Please fix the formatting. You only need one set of triple quotes at the beginning of your code, the text of your code pasted directly in and another triple quotes after.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to access the key followers in the dictionary r, but it is not present in the dictionary. That is why you are getting the KeyError with the message 'followers'.

To fix the error, you can either make sure that the key followers is present in the dictionary r before trying to access it, or you can use the dict.get() method to safely retrieve the value associated with the key follower

Comment: [edit] and Share the full stacktrace

Comment: please write down the code sir @LudoSchmidt